# What's a Regex pattern for 3 consecutive digits increasing or decreasing

Tags: regex

I need a regex pattern to match a sequence of 3 consecutive digits in a string that are consecutively increasing or decreasing.

For example:

These strings should match (xxx123xxx, 789xxxxxx, xxxxxx987, xxxxxx432)

These strings should not match (xxxxxx454, 333xxxxxx, xxx429xxx)

Comment: Why the requirement for a regex? (I don't think this can be done with most regex dialects, Perl's conditional clauses might be able to do it). Better to match for three consecutive digits and then filter for the relationship between them.

Comment: "increasing or decreasing" makes regexs not appropriate for this task

Comment: This is a problem that requires "state" at each point. Consider using a state machine (parser) for this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no other way than listing them:

```
(012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789|987|876|765|654|543|432|321|210)
```

Comment: This is technically the correct answer, but I agree that Regex is not necessarily the best way to accomplish the task. Regex should be used to find the 3 digit pattern and then further testing should be used to find if that 3 digit pattern is consecutively increasing/decreasing.

Comment: @matt.kovacs: That’s a great conclusion.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done simply, but only with defining the valid sets of consecutive digits

(?:012|210|123|321|234|432|345|543|456|654|567|765|678|876|789|987)

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be a very complicated regex. On a project where I had to do something very similar, I ended up matching digit groups and then passing off the actual validation of the digits to a delegate (I was doing this in C++ code; have done something similar on another project in Java in the same way).

If at all possible, this is what I'd recommend doing here. A regex which could do this all by itself would be very difficult to read or maintain.