# Match increasing/decreasing sequences using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'd like to match any string that contains only digits that are increasing or decreasing. This means that these strings would be matched:

```
123, 234567, 0123456789, 87654, 321
```

And these would not:

```
7891011, 1234566789, 987865, 134
```

I was looking for an answer and [all I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185142/whats-a-regex-pattern-for-3-consecutive-digits-increasing-or-decreasing) was that this is not possible to be done using regex. However, I would like to do it in regex, otherwise it'd make a mess in the code.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Regex would not be the appropriate tool to use here

Comment: Regex is a good tool for finding patterns in a string. It does not have any concept of numbers or counting, however. You can usually validate that a number falls within a small range, such as 0..100 but there is no way to determine that those numbers are sequential.

Comment: So it doesn't know ASCII code of a character and compare it to the previous one?

Comment: *"regex, otherwise it'd make a mess"* - did you ever hear the phrase ["now you have two problems"](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)?

Comment: If you make question more generic it may be better: "match any substring from string of unique characters (i.e. sequential digits)".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically it is possible with the use of lookaheads, but it won't look nice.

Logic for ascending pattern:

1. Start from the beginning of string
2. Match current digit only in case if it is followed by next digit or end of string. Move to next position.
3. Repeat 2 until we reach end of string.

Example for 123:

1. Start from the beginning of string
2. Current symbol is 0? No. Ok, skip.
3. Current symbol is 1? Yes. Is it followed by 2 or end of string? Yes. Ok, go to next symbol.
4. Current symbol is 2? Yes. Is it followed by 3 or end of string? Yes. Ok, go to next symbol.
5. Current symbol is 3? Yes. Is it followed by 4 or end of string? Yes. Ok, go to next symbol.
6. Current symbol is 4? No. Current symbol is 5? No. ... Is it end of string? Yes.

Example for 134:

1. Start from the beginning of string
2. Current symbol is 0? No. Ok, skip.
3. Current symbol is 1? Yes. Is it followed by 2 or end of string? No. Error, no match.

Regex to match ascending patterns:

```
^(?:0(?=1|$))?(?:1(?=2|$))?(?:2(?=3|$))?(?:3(?=4|$))?(?:4(?=5|$))?(?:5(?=6|$))?(?:6(?=7|$))?(?:7(?=8|$))?(?:8(?=9|$))?9?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Gnod_i6jOsEFiB8G)

Regex to match descending patterns:

```
^(?:9(?=8|$))?(?:8(?=7|$))?(?:7(?=6|$))?(?:6(?=5|$))?(?:5(?=4|$))?(?:4(?=3|$))?(?:3(?=2|$))?(?:2(?=1|$))?(?:1(?=0|$))?0?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/IewWBd6G-Abyff_T)

Combined together:

```
^((?:0(?=1|$))?(?:1(?=2|$))?(?:2(?=3|$))?(?:3(?=4|$))?(?:4(?=5|$))?(?:5(?=6|$))?(?:6(?=7|$))?(?:7(?=8|$))?(?:8(?=9|$))?9?|(?:9(?=8|$))?(?:8(?=7|$))?(?:7(?=6|$))?(?:6(?=5|$))?(?:5(?=4|$))?(?:4(?=3|$))?(?:3(?=2|$))?(?:2(?=1|$))?(?:1(?=0|$))?0?)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/GB9VUVfmiU9NbBHO)

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lW9kC4/1)

Comment: +1. Info on the construct used - [MSDN:  zero-width positive lookahead assertion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookahead_assertion)

Comment: Wow, thank you for the great answer! Though, it looks scary/big/unreadable, so I might reconsider whether I'll actually use it, but definitely answered my question.

Comment: it's the answer to the question, definitely.  But this is not what Regex was designed for.  It's a terribly roundabout way to save a few lines of code, with a painfully large expression.

Answer (score 1):

The code wouldn't be more of a mess than the regex to do this. Regular expressions are bad at math.

Something like this will do it:

```
bool IsSequentiallyIncreasing(string input)
{
    char? lastDigit = null;

    foreach (char c in input)
    {
        if (!c.IsDigit || (lastDigit != null && c != lastDigit + 1))
        {
            return false;
        }

        lastDigit = c;
    }

    return true;
}
```

So you walk over all characters in the string, and as soon as you encounter a non-digit or a digit that isn't the last digit + 1, you return false.

And do the same for decreasing, and you can simply call `IsSequentiallyIncreasing(input) || IsSequentiallyDecreasing(input)`. I'll leave it up to you to add error handling and merge the two methods into one.

Comment: Yes, I already have a method for checking for a sequence, but I'd rather do it using regex

Comment: What I meant is that I'd *prefer* to do it using regex, but if there's no way for this, then I guess I'll be stuck with a method. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It is possible, but just as ugly. Your regex will look like `(([01|12|23|...|89]){1,}|([98|87|76|...|10]){1,})`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that but this is simply not acceptable since I would have to first do it for 2-digit numbers, than for 3-digit numbers and so on until 10-digit numbers. I was just curious whether there isn't some clever 10-20 character long regex that would do this for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a function `IsSequential`:

```
static bool IsSequential(string input)
{
    var nums = input.Select(Convert.ToInt32);

    int last = nums.First();
    foreach (var num in nums.Skip(1))
    {
        if (num < last) return false;
        last = num;
    }

    return true;
}
```

then just check if each number `IsSequential`, or if it `IsSequential` when reversed.

```
var inputs = @"123, 234567, 0123456789, 87654, 321, 7891011, 1234566789, 987865";
var valids = inputs
                .Split(',')
                .Select(n => n.Trim())
                .Where(n => IsIncreasing(n) || IsIncreasing(new string(n.Reverse().ToArray())))
                .ToList();
```

if you need them to be increasing exactly by 1, use `if(num != last+1)`

Comment: Yep, sounds like that I'll have to go with such a solution! Although, I tried to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

there is no regex patter that can do that but you can use regex to help collect those items

```
List<Match> oMatches = new List<Match>();
String sData = "123, 234567, 0123456789, 87654, 321 , 7891011, 1234566789, 987865";
Regex.Replace(sData, @"\d+", delegate(Match oMatch)//delegate is run for each match as closure
{
    char? oLast = null;
    foreach (char oChar in oMatch.Value)//for each char
    {
        if ((oLast != null && Math.Abs(oChar - oLast) > 1))//not in sequense
            return oMatch.Value;//early return
        oLast = oChar;
    }
    oMatches.Add(oMatch)//add to outside collection
    return oMatch.Value; //return match itself because we don't actually want to replace anything
});
```