# regex to check for subsequent characters

Tags: regex, string, numbers, integer

i would like to ask if it is possible to get a regex to check for subsequent alphabets or numbers in a string such as "abcd" or "1234" 4 characters in succession.

This is for password validation to check if a user is trying to enter a password like "abcd1234"

Thank You

Comment: @KernelPanic: Agreed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer [Match increasing/decreasing sequences using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932885/match-increasing-decreasing-sequences-using-regex), this pattern does close. Through programming you still need to get the first capturing group `\1` and check whether its size is equal to 4. Here you need to set the multi line mode, to allow $ match the end of line.

This is because this regex is capturing all possible groups, however the groups you want has the length of 4, so it should not be a problem.

```
(?x)
(
        (?:a(?=b|$))?
        (?:b(?=c|$))?
        (?:c(?=d|$))?
        (?:d(?=e|$))?
        (?:e(?=f|$))?
        (?:f(?=g|$))?
        (?:g(?=h|$))?
        (?:h(?=i|$))?
        (?:i(?=j|$))?
        (?:j(?=k|$))?
        (?:k(?=l|$))?
        (?:l(?=m|$))?
        (?:m(?=n|$))?
        (?:n(?=o|$))?
        (?:o(?=p|$))?
        (?:p(?=q|$))?
        (?:q(?=r|$))?
        (?:r(?=s|$))?
        (?:s(?=t|$))?
        (?:t(?=u|$))?
        (?:u(?=x|$))?
        (?:x(?=z|$))?
        [a-z]?
    |
        (?:0(?=1|$))?
        (?:1(?=2|$))?
        (?:2(?=3|$))?
        (?:3(?=4|$))?
        (?:4(?=5|$))?
        (?:5(?=6|$))?
        (?:6(?=7|$))?
        (?:7(?=8|$))?
        (?:8(?=9|$))?
        \d?
)
```

On this link you can see the live regex: https://regex101.com/r/xxED4s/2